# Pull the latest from the branch onto local branch

Tags: git, github

Currently learning git and command lines. Sometimes ot can be confusing.

eg:

master

*beta-feature

on local, working on beta-feature branch, there is new changes committed by someone else on the same branch. How do I pull the latest updates on beta-feature without pulling anything from master branch? If pull from master branch into beta-feature it will affect certain stuff.

git pull --rebase on local for beta feature branch or am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you cloned your repository from a remote repository (which is automatically named origin) and that is were the newly committed changes are present, you can pull the specific branch from the remote repository as follows:

```
git pull origin beta-feature
```

This will fetch the data from the remote repository and merge it with the changes in your version of the same branch. To rebase instead of merge add the --rebase flag (after the pull argument).

Comment: it will not fetch all changes from master branch correct?